# sed - how to parse text from some character and send to output separated by comma

Tags: parsing, text, sed

I have a file `test.txt` with content like below:

```
$ cat test.txt 
IA/N1143 1
IA/N1144 1
IA/N1147 1
IA/N1850 0
IA/N2004 0
IA/M2850 0
IA/M2004 0
IA/NTST 0
$
```

I want to parse that file like below with `sed`:

```
N1143;1
N1144;1
N1147;1
N1850;0
N2004;0
M2850;0
M2004;0
```

So, only character with N* & M* plus status 0 and 1 will be sent to output, separated by a semi-colon.

Could you help me by showing how to parse that file with `sed`, `grep` or `awk`?

Comment: Using a regex or replace `IA/` with `;`? perhaps...

Comment: The character shown in the output is a semicolon, not a comma; is the verbiage or the example wrong?

Comment: Well after the question is update it looks totally different .. the arrangement. You may have to replace `IA/` with nothing and then replace space with `;`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superficially, it looks as though you need:

```
sed -n '/^IA\/\([NM][0-9][0-9]*\) \([01]\)$/ s//\1;\2/p' test.txt
```

The `-n` means do not print lines by default.  The search pattern looks for lines that match (very exactly) `IA/` followed by N or M and one or more digits, a space, and a digit 0 or 1 and end of line.  The letter and digit string is captured with `\(...\)`, as is the final digit; the replacement follows the example separating the fields with a semicolon rather than a comma as stated in the question; clearly, to output a comma as stated but not shown is trivial.  The line is printed (the trailing `p`) only when it matches.

As well as the comma versus semicolon issue, this answer assumes that the required output is accurate and the NTST line should not appear.  However, the wording in the question implies that maybe the NTST line should appear as well.  If so, you can simplify the regex by allowing any number of non-blank characters after the N or M:

```
sed -n '/^IA\/\([NM][^]*\) \([01]\)$/ s//\1;\2/p' test.txt
```

It is not clear from that question what should happen to lines such as:

```
IA/N 0
IA/N Z 0
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for my late reply.. Many thanks for all of your tips, guys.. Every tips is working well for my question.. Thanks.. #Supriyanto

Answer (score 0):

```
% sed s/^IA.// < test.txt | sed "s/ /;/"

N1143;1
N1144;1
N1147;1
N1850;0
N2004;0
M2850;0
M2004;0
NTST;0
```

Remove IA appearing at the start first. Then replace spaces by semicolons

**Note** that this also outputs the NTST line. Use Jonathan's solution if that must not be printed.

Comment: Note that the desired output does not include the NTST line.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use perl for this if you like:

```
perl -F -lane 'if(/\/N[\d]+/||/\/M[\d]+/){$F[0]=~s/.*\///g;print join ";",@F}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
IA/N1143 1
IA/N1144 1
IA/N1147 1
IA/N1850 0
IA/N2004 0
IA/M2850 0
IA/M2004 0
IA/NTST 0

> perl -F -lane 'if(/\/N[\d]+/||/\/M[\d]+/){$F[0]=~s/.*\///g;print join ";",@F}' temp
N1143;1
N1144;1
N1147;1
N1850;0
N2004;0
M2850;0
M2004;0
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you say you want ("only character with N* & M* plus status 0 and 1 will be sent to output, separated by a semi-colon"):

```
awk -F'[/ ]' -v OFS=';' '$2~/^[MN]/ && $3~/^[01]$/{print $2,$3}' file
```

and this will instead produce the expected output you posted by making an assumption that the text starting with M or N must be followed by a digit:

```
awk -F'[/ ]' -v OFS=';' '$2~/^[MN][[:digit:]]/ && $3~/^[01]$/{print $2,$3}' file
```